# AJAX Data Won't Load in Multi Select Box during Search

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I've created a search box for keywords and I want to try and use JSON/AJAX to search for keywords to be entered.

I've tried, in vain, for the past 2 hours trying to get this to work and I know I'm missing something but can't put my finger upon it. I just get a message, Results Could not be loaded (this message comes from the cdnjs for select2). When I load the keyword_search.php page, I get the results in expected format (see code below):

I've created a multi-select box

```
<select class="js-example-basic-multiple" multiple="multiple" name="img_keywords[]" style="width:100%">
                <?php
                    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
                    $path .= "/includes/connections/mysqli.php";
                    require($path);

                    $sql = "SELECT * 
                            FROM tbl_photos_keywords_all
                            GROUP BY pa_keyword
                            ";

                    $data = $link->query($sql);

                    $keywords = $row['img_keywords'];
                    $selected = explode(',', $keywords);

                    while($row2 = $data->fetch_assoc()) {

                            $isSelected = in_array($row2['pa_keywordID'], $selected) ? "selected='selected'" : "";

                            echo "<option {$isSelected} value='{$row2['pa_keywordID']}'>{$row2['pa_keyword']}</option>";

                    }
                        $link->close();
                ?>
    </select>
```

And my javascript code is:

```
<script>
       $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2({
            tags: true,
            tokenSeparators: [","],
            createSearchChoice: function (term, data) {

                if (term.trim().length > 0) {
                    if ($(data).filter(function () {
                      return this.text.toLowerCase().localeCompare(term.toLowerCase()) === 0;
                    }).length === 0) {
                        return {
                            id: term,
                            text: term,
                            isNew: true // this is necessary to check if the item is newly added or not
                        };
                    }
                }
            },
            multiple: true,
            minimumInputLength: 1,
            allowClear: true,    

            ajax: {
                url: "keyword_search.php",
                dataType: 'json',
                type: "GET",
                quietMillis: 50,
                data: function (term) {
                    return {
                        term: name
                    };
                },
                results: function (data) {
                    return {
                        results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                            return {
                                id: item.id,
                                text: item.name
                            }
                        })
                    };
                }
            }
    }
            );
            });

    </script>
```

My keyword_search.php file:

```
<?php
    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    $path .= "/includes/connections/mysqli.php";
    require($path);

    $sql = "SELECT * 
            FROM tbl_photos_keywords_all
            ORDER BY pa_keyword
            ";

    $data = $link->query($sql);
    $dataPoints = array();

    while($row2 = $data->fetch_assoc()) {
            $point = array("id" => $row2['pa_keywordID'], "name"=> htmlspecialchars($row2['pa_keyword']));
            array_push($dataPoints, $point);
    }
        echo json_encode($dataPoints, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
        $link->close();
?>
```

Comment: Where is the message "Results Could not be loaded" coming from? I can't see it in your code.

Comment: Try to put a breakpoint in your PHP script and debug your PHP code to see what/how is executed. You can use XDebug with a proper IDE. Also have you enable error reporting and logging?

Comment: Hi Dharman - I am not sure where Results Could Not be loaded is coming from. I suspect it is coming from the Select2 js codes.  I do have error reporting & logging enabled "globally" in the connections script. I am not throwing any errors and that are "reportable" from what I can see. My selectbox still populates with the values based off of the "select" portion of my code. I will look to see if there is something in the Select2 code that is indicating Results Could Not Be Loaded

Comment: the results message is coming from the CDNjs file for select2 cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.full.js

Comment: Did you mean to have the line `echo json_encode($dataPoints, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);` after the while loop by any chance?

Comment: Oops. No. I meant for it to be outside. I've moved it and still no results. THough now, I'm only displaying one set of data when I load the keyword_search.php page instead of significantly more. I've updated the code above to reflect this.

Comment: On another unrelated note, you do not need to close mysqli statements. PHP does it for you.

Comment: You are passing the data in AJAX but you are not reading the JSON payload in PHP. Try to `console.log` the data you get in AJAX response, before you map it.